# can't connect with my account

Tags: support

Is it possible that logging in with facebook has orphaned my existing account (that used the same email)?  I tried password recovery, it only hooked me up to this new account.  I know the old one still exists (I have the id) because I still have email notifications from replies to a question I answered.

I clicked the link in the email, browsed my original profile, it's all there, I just can't login using it.  What do I do?

TIA,
MM

Comment: Mark, what's the ID of your old account?

Comment: My id is 1241224. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide links to both your old and new profiles? Alternatively, use the [Contact us](http://meta.serverfault.com/contact) form to request that they be merged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1241224/mark-mcginty; http://meta.serverfault.com/users/301140/mark-mcginty